# Xamarin.Forms Images Causes Grid Row Height To Excessively Increase

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, grid, row, row-height

The grid is already instantiated with the columns at the start of the code outside the foreach loop, within this loop, rows are being instantiated.

```
foreach (var post in posts)
{
    Frame featuredFrame = new Frame();
    featuredFrame.Padding = 20;
    featuredFrame.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);

    Label postTitle = new Label();
    postTitle.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Subtitle, typeof(Label));

    BoxView titleSeparator = new BoxView();
    titleSeparator.Color = Color.Gray;
    titleSeparator.HeightRequest = 1;
    titleSeparator.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;

    Image postFeaturedImage = new Image();
    postFeaturedImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(imageUri);
    postFeaturedImage.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill;

    BoxView imageSeparator = new BoxView();
    imageSeparator.Color = Color.Gray;
    imageSeparator.HeightRequest = 2;
    imageSeparator.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;

    Label publishDate = new Label();
    publishDate.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Caption, typeof(Label));

    StackLayout postDetails = new StackLayout();
    postDetails.Children.Add(postTitle);
    postDetails.Children.Add(titleSeparator);
    postDetails.Children.Add(postFeaturedImage);
    postDetails.Children.Add(imageSeparator);
    postDetails.Children.Add(publishDate);
    postDetails.Margin = new Thickness(0);
    postDetails.Padding = new Thickness(0);

    featuredFrame.Content = postDetails;

    postGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
    postGrid.Children.Add(featuredFrame, columnNumber, rowNumber);
}
```

As you can see, the rows are being created with the height set to Auto, this should mean the rows are the same height as the children.

This is the result of the code above:

[image: Result With Pictures]

This is the result of the code above with `postDetails.Children.Add(postFeaturedImage);` commented out:

[image: Result without pictures]

In the screenshot with the images, there is a lot of blank space below the publish date-time text. In the screenshot without the images, this blank space is gone.

I need the pictures visible, but the blank space shouldn't be there. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this issue just happened in IOS? You can try to set the specific `HeightRequest` for your image or your `Frame`, I test it in Android with diferent height of picture, this result like this screenshot.: https://imgur.com/a/Lbdb1TC, it seems worked as normal.

Comment: Nope, I've tested on Android too and the issue is there as well. Setting a specific ```HeightRequest``` causes the grid to glitch, for example, it overlaps and doesn't fit inside the ```ScrollView```

Comment: Just try to use CollectionView https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/ This might be way more correct than trying to build all that grid on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue (that's how I found the question) and I have managed to fix it.

I solved the problem by adding `VerticalOptions` like this:

`postDetails.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;`

and make sure that you have `Height = GridLength.Auto` for the `RowDefinition`.